# How to distinguish constant lists from dynamically created lists?

Tags: reference, scheme

I'm a student, have a test tomorrow, and I saw that last year there was this question: Write a scheme code that distinguish `'(a b)` from `(list 'a 'b)`, without using side effect (no `set!`, `set-car!` ..)
I have no idea how to do this. has anyone an idea?

The reason that there is a difference is that `'(a b)` creates a static object in the memory, that is referenced. And `(list 'a 'b)` is an application that creates a dynamic memory object.

---

My teacher is expecting a code that either gives a different answer, according to the input, or that one input causes an infinite loop.

An example for code that uses side effects:

```
(define lst (lambda () '(a b)))
(set-car! (lst) 'g)
(display (lst)) (newline)
;;; prints (g b)

(define lst1 (lambda () (list 'a 'b)))
(set-car! (lst1) 'g)
(display (lst1)) (newline)
;;; prints (a b)
```

The reason is that the `lambda` is postponing the computation of the value, and cause in the case of `(list 'a 'b)` the creation of a new list each time `(lst1)` is called.

For those who complain that the question is not good: the course is about compilers and he wants us to understand what effects everything has until the code-generation.

Comment: dynamically write? (see title)

Comment: I don't think it is generally possible to do so. Maybe on a specific implementation, but I don't see the point.

Comment: Agreed.  The quiz problem as stated seems poorly constructed because it's skirting uncomfortably close to places where the behavior is implementation-dependent (i.e. undefined behavior).  And the whole thing about not using mutablity kills what makes this subject actually useful to real programmers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an assumption to the question that objects can be distinguished by memory location.  See [Equivalence Predicates](http://schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/) in section 6.1, especially the description of **eqv?**.

Specifically:

```
(define x '(a b))
(define y (list 'a 'b))

(eqv? x y)
(eqv? y x)
(eqv? x x)
(eqv? y y)
```

all have well-defined values.

As you note,

```
(eqv? '(a b) '(a b))
```

is implementation specific.  If your exam question is asking what will happen in an undefined siutation, I'm very tempted to reply "Foo".  :)  Without any more context, it's a nonsense question.

On the other hand,

```
(eqv? (list 'a 'b) (list 'a 'b))
```

is well defined.

Comment: 1. it says that for eq? and eqv? its unspecified. how does that help? 2. is that true also in standard scheme? or just in R5RS?

Comment: Not all things are unspecified.  For the very narrow, narrow situation described by your quiz question, eq? and eqv? can tell the difference between '(1 2) and (list 1 2).  But as commented earlier, yeah, this question isn't so great.  What would make the problem more relevant is to compare mutable values, like vectors, where it actually does matter to have a mental model of memory in order to understand the question.

Comment: To specify: you stated that the two values are in distinct locations.  Under that scenario, eqv? is defined.

Comment: Well, the issue if the question is good or not isn't relevant to me - I either answer, or don't get the points. -- about the eqv? it's undefined for (eqv? '(a b) '(a b)) - so (for example in chez scheme) you can't tell if you tested (eqv? '(a b) '(a b)) or (eqv? '(a b) (list 'a 'b)) - i updated the question.

Comment: I can't speak for other instructors, but I claim that a well-worded explanation of why the question isn't a good one should be worth full points.